# Why a Macro in Google Sheets works fine when I run it, but not when I schedule it with a simple daily time trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I recently created a Macro in Google Sheets, and after a lot of trial-and-error, got it to work perfectly and consistently. I've tried it nearly 100 times by selecting the Macro within the Google Sheets file, and it hasn't ever failed.

However, I wanted to schedule the Macro to run once daily, in order to get the maximum functionality out of it. So, using Google Apps Script, I added a trigger for the Macro, with the following details: *"Head"* runs at deployment; *"Time-Driven"* event source; *"Day timer"* type of time based trigger; *"1 am-2 am"* time of day.

However, every time the Macro is triggered to run automatically, it has failed, each time giving me an error notice at 1:40 am with the error message of: *"Exception: A row group does not exist with index 19 and group depth 1."*

I believe this is in reference to the first part of the Macro (which uses Absolute Cell references, not relative), in which I un-collapse a certain group of rows (beginning at row 19) and then ungroup them. Again, **this works perfectly when I click to run the exact same Macro myself within Google Sheets, so I can't understand what the issue might be that won't allow it to run successfully when triggered by time.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to [so].  How do you created the "macro"? Do you used the Google Sheets macro recorder? Do you imported an script as a Google Sheets macro?

Comment: Also it will be very helpful if you add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

When you run a script it's very likely that you opened the spreadsheet in the web browser so methods like the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` returns the corresponding object based on what sheet you have opened, what cell you have selected etc., but when a a function called by a time-driven trigger runs the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` returns the first sheet, and other methods might return something different than what you are expecting.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! So just to clarify, you're saying that the issue may be that when I run the Macro myself, I do so when I'm already on the correct/intended sheet. But, when the Macro runs via a time-based trigger, it's going to run on the first sheet of the file (which in this case, is not the sheet I want it to run on), which is why it is messing up?

Comment: So, if that's the case--is there a way to change the code away from "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()" to some code that knows to operate within my sheet of choice? Is there a way to code that in?          Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You might replace `getActiveSheet()` by `getSheetByName(name)` but I don't know if that will be enough. I suggest you to create a  [mcve] then if you still need helps, post a new question including the code.